# Java - Quartz Job working on Debug Tomcat, but not on separate Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, quartz-scheduler, scheduling

I configured a Quartz job, which fires in the eclipse's Debug Tomcat that comes with Spring. But if I deploy my application to my separate Tomcat installation, the job doesn't fire.

Here's my quartz-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="de.java.scheduling" />

<bean name="issueSyncJobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobClass" value="de.java.scheduling.IssueSyncJob" />
    <property name="durability" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="cronTrigger"  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="issueSyncJobDetail" />
    <property name="cronExpression" value="0/10 * * ? * MON-FRI" />
</bean>

<!-- Scheduler factory bean to glue together jobDetails and triggers to Configure Quartz Scheduler -->
<bean  class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="issueSyncJobDetail" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="cronTrigger" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Any idea what might be the cause for the job not triggering once deployed on my Tomcat?

Comment: It seems that there is no mistake in your xml, can you provide more infomation,another option, I have made a mistake like yours , I debug at tomcat in my eclipse then I package it into a war file then put it into my webapps folder then start tomcat with eclipse , obvious it doesn`t work , so have you made a mistake like me ?

Comment: Why didn't it work for you on your standalone Tomcat? What was the mistake?